# How to change data and graph using buttons in plotly python?

Tags: python, plotly

Based on this code directly from plotly's tut page:

https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/

Now, what if I want to change not just the chart type but rather the data source and its chart type? 
Is it possible?

EDIT:

I've played with this settings:

```
data1 = go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale='Viridis')
data2 = go.Heatmap(z=df.values.tolist())

buttons=list([   
            dict(
                args=[data1],
                label='3D Surface',
                method='restyle'
            ),
            dict(
                args=[data2],
                label='Heatmap',
                method='restyle'
            )             
        ])
```

However, the graphs are shown, but overlayed. And when I click any item in the dropdown menu, the graph is completely gone.

Comment: Doesn't the `restyle` method described on that page give an example how to change the data with `py.iplot(dict(data=data, layout=layout), ...)`? NB: you should include the code you have tried with *embedded* in your question. It is not enough to refer to an external site.

Comment: Just added some lines of my code...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found a solution myself, that is actually based on the tut:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader as web

df = web.DataReader("aapl", 'google',
                    datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                    datetime(2016, 7, 1))

trace_high = go.Bar(    x=df.index,
                        y=df.High,
                        name='High')

trace_low = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                       y=df.Low,
                       name='Low',
                       line=dict(color='#F06A6A'))

data = [trace_high, trace_low]


updatemenus = list([
    dict(active=-1,
         buttons=list([   
            dict(label = 'High',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [True, False]},
                         {'title': 'Yahoo High'}]),

            dict(label = 'Low',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [False, True]},
                         {'title': 'Yahoo Low'}])
        ]),
    )
])

layout = dict(title='Yahoo', showlegend=False,
              updatemenus=updatemenus)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, auto_open=False, show_link=False)
```

Comment: this does not work for me. A plot is generated but nothing happens when I try to select different plot (i.e., Low or High).