# Switch between scatterpolar plots in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am wanting to create an interactive plotly plot in Python where I switch between two scatterpolar plots (a logged version and a linear version). I tried using the same idea used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132943/how-to-change-data-and-graph-using-buttons-in-plotly-python) with no luck. My code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Get data
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpudil/projects/master/slc.csv"
slc_df = pd.read_csv(url)

fig_log = go.Figure(data=
    go.Scatterpolar(
        r = list(slc_df['distance']),
        theta = list(slc_df['bearing']),
        mode = 'markers',   
        name = 'log'
    ))


fig_log.update_layout(

    polar = dict(
      radialaxis = dict(type = "log", tickangle = 45),
        angularaxis = dict(
            thetaunit = "degrees",
            dtick = 45,
            rotation=90,
            direction = "clockwise",
            tickmode="array",
            tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
            ticktext=["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]
            )
    ))




fig_linear = go.Figure(data=
    go.Scatterpolar(
        r = list(slc_df['distance']),
        theta = list(slc_df['bearing']),
        mode = 'markers',   
        name='linear'
    ))


fig_linear.update_layout(
    polar = dict(
      radialaxis = dict(type = "linear", tickangle = 45),
        angularaxis = dict(
            thetaunit = "degrees",
            dtick = 45,
            rotation=90,
            direction = "clockwise",
            tickmode="array",
            tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
            ticktext=["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]
            ),
    ))



data = [fig_log, fig_linear]


updatemenus = list([
    dict(active=-1,
         buttons=list([   
            dict(label = 'log',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [True, False]},
                         {'title': 'Logged Distance'}]),

            dict(label = 'linear',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [False, True]},
                         {'title': 'Linear Distance'}])
        ]),
    )
])

layout = dict(title='Photos near SLC', showlegend=False,
              updatemenus=updatemenus)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, auto_open=False, show_link=False)
```

However, I get the Value Error: Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property. Am I doing something wrong here?

Note 1: The plots themselves show up just fine individually.

Note 2: The dataset can be accessed [here](https://github.com/mpudil/projects/blob/master/slc.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's possible to use buttons with one trace only.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Get data
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpudil/projects/master/slc.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

trace = go.Scatterpolar(
        r = df['distance'],
        theta = df['bearing'],
        mode = 'markers',   
        name = 'log')

# here there are your buttons
updatemenus = list([
    dict(active=0,
         buttons=list([dict(label="Linear",  
                         method="relayout", 
                         args=[{"polar.radialaxis.type": "linear"}]),
                    dict(label="Log", 
                         method="relayout", 
                         args=[{"polar.radialaxis.type": "log"}]),
                                  ]),
        )
    ])

# here the layout (which is the same in the two cases)
layout = dict(polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(tickangle=45),
    angularaxis=dict(
            thetaunit="degrees",
            dtick = 45,
            rotation=90,
            direction = "clockwise",
            tickmode="array",
            tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
            ticktext=["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]
            )),
    updatemenus=updatemenus)

fig = go.Figure(data=trace, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Alternatively if you want to use `update_layout` using `trace` and `updatemenus` as before

```py
fig = go.Figure(trace)
fig = fig.update_layout(polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(tickangle=45),
    angularaxis=dict(
            thetaunit="degrees",
            dtick = 45,
            rotation=90,
            direction = "clockwise",
            tickmode="array",
            tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
            ticktext=["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]
            )),
    updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```